# Compare Two Tables on Snowflake Where it Contains NULL Values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, querying

Hello everyone i am facing an issue, i.e
Table T1 with schema

| ID | TYPE | MODEL_ID | FREQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 234 | 5 |
| 2 | SUV | 12 | 6 |
| 3 | EV | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | HV | NULL | NULL |

TABLE T2 with schema and data

| ID | TYPE | MODEL_ID | FREQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | EV | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | HV | NULL | NULL |

Now i am checking the working with the following query,

```
SELECT *  FROM T1 AS T, T2 AS N
  WHERE T.ID = N.ID AND T.TYPE = N.TYPE AND T.MODEL_ID = N.MODEL_ID AND T.FREQ = N.FREQ
```

The result is empty set, i knew that i need to implement a null safe query but to this scenario how do i achieve it.

**Note: Here ID is not an identifier, so should compare with every column in the table.**

Comment: Hi @The_Third_Eye - please add your expected result - because are you trying to get what's in both tables or something else??   Also the data - are you really intending to ignore model ID for EVs - or have you just got wonky data at the moment...

Comment: sorry for the late reply it was wonky data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [IS NOT DISTINCT FROM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from.html) to perform NULL-safe comparison:

> Compares whether two expressions are equal (or not equal). The function is NULL-safe, meaning it treats NULLs as known values for comparing equality.

```
SELECT *  
FROM T1 AS T, T2 AS N 
WHERE T.ID       IS NOT DISTINCT FROM N.ID 
  AND T.TYPE     IS NOT DISTINCT FROM N.TYPE 
  AND T.MODEL_ID IS NOT DISTINCT FROM N.MODEL_ID 
  AND T.FREQ     IS NOT DISTINCT FROM N.FREQ;
```

---

Another simpler option is usage of [INTERSECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#intersect) set operator:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM T2;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1d27ef78f70c17a26e8cbf3640e86be6)**

Comment: Second method i have uesd it, but rather i need the first method as there is another operation i need to perform, thanks @LukaszSzozda for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
SELECT *  
FROM T1 AS T, T2 AS N 
WHERE EQUAL_NULL(T.ID,N.ID)
  AND EQUAL_NULL(T.TYPE,N.TYPE)
  AND EQUAL_NULL(T.MODEL_ID,N.MODEL_ID)
  AND EQUAL_NULL(T.FREQ,N.FREQ);
```